# Sending data from one batch to another with amount of data

Tags: apex, batch, stateful

I have 2 Batches: Batch_A and Batch_B.

I'm calling Batch_B in the finish method of Batch_A.

I Implemented Database.Stateful to do so, and I'm wondering :

How much Data can I send from one batch to another, or in other words - How much Data can Batch_A remember to pass to Batch_B?

The Data I send from Batch_A to Batch_B is a Map of an object as the key with Set of String in the value.

```
global class Batch_A implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    Map<Sobject,Set<String>> myMap= new Map<Sobject,Set<String>>();
    String query;

    global Batch_A() {

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        query = 'SOME QUERY'

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Sobject> scope) {   
     // After a loop throtgh scope and its related : 
          myMap.put(Sobject,set<String>);

         }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new Batch_B(this.myMap), 200);
    }

}



global class Batch_B implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    Map<Sobject,Set<String>> myMap = new Map<Sobject,Set<String>>();
    String query;

    global Batch_B (Map<Sobject,Set<String>> mapValues) {
        //Check the values that sent from Batch_A
        System.debug('mapValues In Constructor -> ' + mapValues);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         //Some Start logic
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
       //Some Execute logic
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         //Some Finish logic
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it would be good to remember that adding Stateful interface to the batch drastically decreases its performance. If you create mapping based on records (and it seems so) it is probably much better idea to actually store the strings on the records.

Answering your question the heap size limit for asynchronous apex is 12MB, so the answer really varies depending on the size of the strings and complexity of the records. :)

Comment: 2kb is the flat "charge" against the Salesforce record storage limit for most records. It's not equivalent to the amount of heap storage those records take, which will vary based on what fields are queried (e.g., long text fields may be much larger, as you allude to here).

Comment: @DavidReed thank you for insight! This is actually very good point! I am editing the response to do not provide misleading information!

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answers. It helped me and actually added more questions about this subject.
I created another question because I wanted to expose it to more people.
Thanks again.


-----

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264804/batch-sending-data-from-one-batch-to-another