# Batch - Sending data from one batch to another

Tags: apex, batch, bestpractice, stateful

I having a little issue to understand the concept of passing params via batches.

I have two batches which I would like to send data between them.

Batch A creates a `Map<sObject,Set<String>>` and in the execute method, I put data in it.

After that, I would like to send this Map to batch B.

1. Should I implement **Database.Stateful** at this case? I know **Database.Stateful** used for passing data between executing method of the **same** batch. for example, counting or sum a field.

Of course if the batch will be split to more than one execute I will need **Database.Stateful** for adding the values of the different executes to the Map, but do I need **Database.Stateful** for passing data through different batches?

2. What it means: That **Database.Stateful** will drastically decrease its performance? How it manifests itself? Only the time of execution?
3. Would be better to save the data in a custom object and in the second batch query the data and use it? (of course it individual, I'm talking when I need to pass a Map of Object with Set  ).
4. Assuming that the second Batch (Batch_B) that executed in the finish method is stuck in the queue.
   How the data (Map) is saved for this batch? where it saves the data? How can I know that the Data will not be deleted or override by other batch processes? How many Data can I send and Save?
5. Other Best Practice and Ideas will be much appreciated!

Thanks and sorry for this many questions.

A simple code is posted down below.

**BATCH A :**  -------------------------------------

```
global class Batch_A implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {
    Map<Sobject,Set<String>> myMap= new Map<Sobject,Set<String>>();
    String query;

    global Batch_A() {

    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        query = 'SOME QUERY'

        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Sobject> scope) {   
     // After a loop throtgh scope and its related : 
          myMap.put(Sobject,set<String>);

         }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
        Id batchJobId = Database.executeBatch(new Batch_B(this.myMap), 200);
    }

}
```

**BATCH B :**  -------------------------------------

```
global class Batch_B implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    Map<Sobject,Set<String>> myMap = new Map<Sobject,Set<String>>();
    String query;

    global Batch_B (Map<Sobject,Set<String>> mapValues) {
        //Check the values that sent from Batch_A
        System.debug('mapValues In Constructor -> ' + mapValues);
    }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         //Some Start logic
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {
       //Some Execute logic
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
         //Some Finish logic
    }

}
```

Comment: What issue with passing data between batches do you have now? From your code I can see, that it should work fine given that you actually use `mapValues` in the second batch. Let me rephrase it, how do you want to use `mapValues` in batch B exactly?

Comment: Hi @Eduard,
The Map is passing between the Batch as excepted.
 There is no issue, except understanding some concepts.
Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I implement Database.Stateful at this case? I know
>   Database.Stateful used for passing data between executing method of
>   the same batch. for example, counting or sum a field. Of course if the
>   batch will be split to more than one execute I will need
>   Database.Stateful for adding the values of the different executes to
>   the Map, but do I need Database.Stateful for passing data through
>   different batches?

YES - the finish() method executes in its own transaction so in order to pass the map to the next batch object, you need Database.Stateful

> What it means: That Database.Stateful will drastically decrease its
>   performance? How it manifests itself? Only the time of execution?

The biggest issue you will have is heap size as if the map is very large, you will exceed heap

> Would be better to save the data in a custom object and in the second
>   batch query the data and use it? (of course it individual, I'm talking
>   when I need to pass a Map of Object with Set ).

This is clearly the most extensible and would allow for millions of rows. You would of course need a predictable query to find the values created by the first batch as passing millions of ids from batch 1 to batch 2 will not work

> Assuming that the second Batch (Batch_B) that executed in the finish
>   method is stuck in the queue. How the data (Map) is saved for this
>   batch? where it saves the data? How can I know that the Data will not
>   be deleted or override by other batch processes? How many Data can I
>   send and Save?

The object for the second batch is serialized by SFDC with its constructor arguments. Nothing will be lost

Comment: Applause my friend!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Since you have many questions, I will answer one for now.

> Should I implement Database.Stateful at this case?

Well, it depends on what you actually need. If you want to use `mapValues` in all `execute` runs, than yes you need to implement `Database.Stateful`. It will ensure that state, i.e. values in `mapValues`,  is preserved during the execution. If you just need to initialize batch B with `mapValues`, e.g. use data from `mapValues` to build the `query` string, then you won't need `Database.Stateful`.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you took will work but as you implemented `Database.Stateful` and adding all your processed data to the map chances are there to get heap size exception. You can bypass this by calling another asynchronous process (take an example of Queue) after all data processed.

```
Batch_A 
{
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Sobject> scope) {
        // After a loop throtgh scope and its related :
        myMap.put(Sobject,set<String>);

        //Initialsie your Queue and pass the parameters you want to pass to Batch_B 
        YourQueue queObj = new YourQueue(myMap);
        Id queID = System.enqueueJob(queObj);
    }
}
```

//--------------

```
public with sharing class YourQueue implements Queueable
{

    Map<Sobject,Set<String>> myMapQ;

    public YourQueue(Map<Sobject,Set<String>> myMapFromBatA)
    {
        this.myMapQ = myMapFromBatA;
    }

    public void execute(QueueableContext context)
    {
            if(myMapQ != null && myMapQ.size() > 0)
            {
                Batch_B btchObjB = new Batch_B(myMapQ);
                Id batchBId = Database.executeBatch(btchObjB,200);
            }
            else
            {
                //Do your exception handeling
            }
    }
}
```

//------

```
Batch_B ....
{
    // Use the same code
}
```

This way you can bypass storing processed data in memory.